# Linear Independence, Span, REF

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

We wish to show that the list $(1,2-4),(7,-5,6)$ is linearly independent in $\mathbb{F}^3$ but is not a basis of $\mathbb{F}^3$ because it does not span $\mathbb{F}^3$
Then for some $v\in\mathbb{F}^3, \hspace{0.5em}v = (a,b,c), \hspace{0.5em} \forall a,b,c\in\mathbb{F}$.
We know that if we write the vectors as column vectors in an augmented matrix and use Gaussian Elimination until REF then the coefficient matrix part is $3\times2$, so if we obtain $m$ leading ones the vectors span $\mathbb{F^3}$ and if we obtain $n$ leading ones then the vectors are linearly indepdent.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 7 & a\\
2 & -5 & b\\
-4 & 6 & c
\end{pmatrix}
\longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 7 & a\\
0 & 1 & \frac{b-2a}{-19}\\
0 & 1 & \frac{4a+c}{36}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So then we have 3 leading ones since the first one zero element in each row is 1 thus as stated above then the vectors span the space and are not linearly independent. This is clearly nonsense! What went wrong.
If now we consider another example for reference,
The list is $(1,2),(3,5),(4,13)$ spans $\mathbb{F^2}$ but is not a basis of $\mathbb{F^2}$ because it is not linearly independent.
Then using the same technique as above we have,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 4 & a\\
2 & 5 & 13 & b
\end{pmatrix}
\longrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 4 & a\\
0 & 1 & -5 & 2a-b
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So we have 2 leading ones and an 2 \times 3 coefficient part of the matrix and m=2 and n=3 so the vectors are linearly dependent and span the space which is reasonable but why didnt the before work?

Comment: I think I have mixed up the defintion I think it should be if there are n leading ones then it spans the space and if there are m leading ones there vectors are linearly independent because then it works. Since there are 3 leading ones and m=3 so there are linearly independent and then n=2 so it does not span the space. Right?

Comment: The sentence "Then for some $v\in\mathbb{F}^3$, $v=(a,b,c)$, $\forall a,b,c\in \mathbb{F}$" does not make any sense to me. It doesn't even parse, For some $v$, *what*? Why is *some* $v$ equal to *all* possible $(a,b,c)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say I follow some of the grittier details of your proof, but I think you're trying to use the following:

> Suppose $v_1, \ldots, v_n \in \Bbb{F}^m$. Let $A = \left(\begin{array}{c|c} v_1 & v_2 & \cdots & v_n \end{array}\right)$, and suppose $B$ is any row-echelon form of $A$. Then $\{v_i : B \text{ has a leading $1$ in column } i \}$ is a basis for $\operatorname{span} \{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$, and hence are linearly independent.

In your first example, the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 7 & a\\
0 & 1 & \frac{b-2a}{-19}\\
0 & \color{red}1 & \frac{4a+c}{36}
\end{pmatrix}$$
is **not** in row-echelon form, as the entry in red lies below a leading $1$, but is not $0$. To use the theorem, you'd have to subtract row $2$ from row $3$, to get:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 7 & a\\
0 & 1 & \frac{b-2a}{-19}\\
0 & 0 & \frac{4a+c}{36} + \frac{b-2a}{19}
\end{pmatrix}.$$
I'm not going to bother simplifying this expression in the bottom right, nor will I check that your reductions so far are valid. But, assuming everything is right so far, then this matrix will be row-echelon form if and only if
$$\frac{4a+c}{36} + \frac{b-2a}{19} = 0. \tag{$\star$}$$
If the above does not hold for this $a, b, c$, then dividing through by the non-zero scalar will yield the row-echelon form
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 7 & a\\
0 & 1 & \frac{b-2a}{-19}\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
In this case, there is a leading $1$ in each column, so the three columns, including the arbitrary vector, is linearly independent. So, as long as $(\star)$ is false, the vectors $(1,2-4),(7,-5,6),(a,b,c)$ are linearly independent and a basis.

If $(\star)$ is true, then the row-echelon form will be
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 7 & a\\
0 & 1 & \frac{b-2a}{-19}\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},$$
and only the first two columns are necessary to span the columnspace. This makes $(a,b,c)$ redundant, so $(1,2-4),(7,-5,6),(a,b,c)$ is linearly dependent, and hence cannot span $\Bbb{F}^3$. Essentially, whether $(1,2-4),(7,-5,6),(a,b,c)$ is a basis depends on whether $(\star)$ is true or false.

In your second example, you've reduced the matrix down to a row-echelon form matrix, which has leading $1$s only in the first and second column. This is true, regardless of the value of $a$ and $b$. So, the set given is never linearly independent, and can be reduced down to a linearly independent set $\{(1, 2), (3, 5)\}$.